# Email writing past perfect tense

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing an email requesting not to dedudct loss of pay for the leave I have not taken.

Is my below sentence construction is correct ?

a) Please do not deduct My loss of pay as I did not bring my attendance card..

Or

b) Please do not deduct My loss of pay as I had not brought my attendance card.

Answer (score 1):

Both "did not" and "had not" appear to be plausible verb tenses. Let's start with a)

> a) Please do not deduct My loss of pay as I did not bring my attendance card.

- "deduct My loss of pay" does not sound correct. "deduct" and "loss" may be redundant such that one of them could be removed.
- the second part of the sentence would be clearer if the time/day were provided.

Intermediate attempt at the sentence:

> c) Please do not deduct my pay, as I did not bring my attendance card on Wednesday.

However, strictly speaking, I think "deduct my pay" is not correct either. "reduce my pay/paycheck" is another option.

Next, another rewording:

> d) Please do not deduct any money from my paycheck on Wednesday. I had forgotten my attendance card.

Ok.

Next, a total rewrite just for fun:

> e) Hi,
>   I wish to apologize, on Wednesday at work I forgot to bring my attendance card. Please do not deduct any pay for that day, since I was present. You may confirm that with (name of co-worker or manager).

So, d) and e) may be interesting answers.

Answer (score 0):

See Sam's answer for a good practical answer.  I'm adding this answer to clarify the grammar rules:

In formal English, your original sentence should only use the simple past "didn't bring".  This is because the strict grammar rule is that the [past perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect) "had brought" can only be used for *the past of the past*, for example:

> I see that you deducted my pay last Friday, because I hadn't brought my attendance card the previous week.

*(Simple past "deducted" happened at time "last Friday"; while past perfect "hadn't brought" is at time "the previous week" (ie, the past of last Friday).)*

On the other hand, sometimes you will hear people use the past perfect to soften the tone of stating an unpleasant fact, even if it doesn't meet the strict grammar rules for this tense.  This seems to be a form of [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection).  In this light, it's possible for a native speaker to use "hadn't brought" even if not describing the past of the past.